# How to display only limited results in angularjs on first time

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, pull-to-refresh

I am newbie to AngularJS and Ajax request.  I have made a demo in that I am making an Ajax request tot remote data and listing it into a list; now I want to show only 10 results at first when page is loaded first time, then after I want to display next 10 results when the list is scrolled down.

I have made also one demo, but in that the list goes infinite, each time making HTTP requests unnecessarily.  It should make only one HTTP request, and display 10 results.  It should not make another request until the user scrolls, when it should fetch the next 10 results.

Here's my code:

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
         
               <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>    
  <script src="angular/angular-touch.js"></script>  
  
   <script src="app.js"></script>    

    </head>
   
    <body>
      
        
        <div data-ng-app='demo'>
  <div data-ng-controller='MainController'>
    <ul class='hello' when-scrolled='more()'>
      <li data-ng-repeat='item in items'>
        {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div data-ng-show='loading'>Loading</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>INFINITE SCROLLING IN ANGULARJS</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
var caymanauth ='MTIzNDU2ODk6ZUVqVFpmcnRJMQ==';
app = angular.module("demo", []);
var API_HOST ='http://caymanafterwork.netcluesdemo.com/beta';
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {

  // the array which represents the list
  $scope.items = ["1. Scroll the list to load more"];
  $scope.loading = true;

  // this function fetches a random text and adds it to array
  $scope.more = function() {
    $http({
//      method: "GET",
//      url: "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1"

 method: 'POST',
            url:  API_HOST+'/webservice/listinglist',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'caymanauth': caymanauth
            },
                                  data: "&Start="+0+"&Pagesize="+6+"&SearchTxt="+''+"&FilterTxt="+''+"&FilterStarSearch="+''+"&FilterPriceSearch="+''+"&FilterLocationSearch="+''+"&FilterCuisineSearch="+''+"&FilterCategorySearch="+''+"&FkCategory=1"
          
    }).success(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("========my response is=============",data);
      // returned data contains an array of 2 sentences
//      for (line in data) {
//        newItem = ($scope.items.length + 1) + ". " + data[line];
//        $scope.items.push(newItem);
//      }

   for (var i = 0 ; i< data['Details'].length ; i++)
            {
              
                      var newItem =  ($scope.items.length + 1) + ". "+data['Details'][i]['varTitle'];
           $scope.items.push(newItem); 
         
             $scope.loading = true;
                    
            }
                        $scope.loading = false;
              
    
    });
  };

  // we call the function twice to populate the list
  $scope.more();
});

// we create a simple directive to modify behavior of <ul>
app.directive("whenScrolled", function() {
  return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
      raw = elem[0];

      // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
      elem.bind("scroll", function() {
        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight + 5 >= raw.scrollHeight) {
          scope.loading = true;

          // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
          scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ui-scroll](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll).

It is a replacement for ngRepeat and should give you the functionality you need.

Comment: i know,it bro.and used it if you have seen my code..!! my question is i want to make http call once,but show only first 10 results then when we scroll down next 10 results should be loaded by displaying a loading message.are you getting me?

Answer (score 0):

What we did is make a directive that binds to the scroll event of the window and calls a scope function to load the data.

Or you could use http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html or
http://aslamhadi.com/infinite-scrolling-with-angularjs/  .